# Difference between Hyperledger Projects

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain

There are around 5 projects under Hyperledger. I don't find any material which talks about distinctive features of every framework, how each framework is different from each other, when to use each? It would be of great help if someone provide that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperledger is a distributed ledger technology implementation of the Linux foundation with a some high-profile partners (IBM and Intel among others).  The 5 projects under the Hyperledger banner are: fabric, sawtooth, indy, burrow, and Iroha.  [Here's a good article explaining the differences](https://www.sdxcentral.com/articles/news/whats-the-difference-between-the-5-hyperledger-blockchain-projects/2017/09/)
In a nutshell fabric is the actual blockchain component that allows for 'plug-ins' of different types of consensus mechanisms.  Consensus mechanisms are at the heart of blockchain and Sawtooth uses POET, proof of elapsed time, in an effort to speed up the process while making it less resource intensive (e.g., less electricity than BTCs proof of work (POW).  Indy is an attempt to tackle the problem of Identity management, burrow is a smart contract implementation and Iroha folds in mobility components.  [To learn more consider this edx course from the Linux foundation](https://www.edx.org/course/blockchain-business-introduction-linuxfoundationx-lfs171x)
It will answer many of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019 there are more frameworks/tools under Hyperledger umbrella,

**Update Aug 29th 2019: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated**

Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated and they suggested everyone to use Fabric instead.

Useful links:

https://www.hyperledger.org/projects
https://101blockchains.com/hyperledger-blockchain/

Below image is taken from 101blockchain.com

[image]